# Data Indexing for intermediate tables

Tags: database, indexing

I have a Users table a Network table and Network_tab table. I need to associate users with a Network_tab and know what network it is for - (A Network_tab can be on any Network.) The best way I can see of doing this to ensure I can associate a user to a Network tab for a Network is to created a User_Network_tab table, which contains the UserId, NetworkId and Network-tabId.

Would it be sensible to assume that indexing all three fields within the User_Network_tab table would be the best option and would not cause an slow down when selecting al the details out? I need more information about the User the Netowork and the Network_tab than just the Ids.

Any advice of a better way in doing this would be appreciated as well.

Thanks Guys.